# Four straight same scaled buttons in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-button

I need a sample layout with 4 same size buttons and for same margins from every side (propably relative layout). Just want them to looks nice and straight. I tried something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMainFindInteractions"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:text="@string/findInteraction"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMainCheckMap"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMainFindReplacements"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:text="@string/find_replacement"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMainSettings"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:text="@string/checkMap"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I can't find the way to size those 4 buttons in the same way.

2nd question: why inside of activity im looking for:

```
findReplacementsButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonMainFindReplacements);
```

It returns me a linearlayout? This does not make sense..

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMainFindInteractions"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:text="@string/findInteraction"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonMainFindInteractions"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonMainFindInteractions"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMainCheckMap"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonMainFindInteractions"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMainFindReplacements"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:text="@string/find_replacement"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


    <Button
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonMainFindReplacements"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonMainFindReplacements"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMainSettings"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:text="@string/checkMap"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Great, just need to move those scaled buttons, and it seems to look perfectly.

Comment: If you need any help, let me know. I am open to help